# ActionBar-PullToRefresh animation

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to use Chris Banes' ActionBar-PullToRefresh in an app. I've got it working for the most part, but I can't see where I'm supposed to set the animation for displaying the headerView. On the [customization](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/blob/master/Customisation.md) page of the github repo it says to use `PullToRefresh.Options` and set the `headerInAnimation`/`headerOutAnimation` values, but I can't see any references to them in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this when your work is done and you'll hide the Indeterminate progresseBar :

```
mPullToRefreshAttacher.setRefreshComplete();
```

Comment: I've got it successfully displaying, I just can't see where to set the in/out animations. so to change the slide-in/out animations when pulling

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fire the animations manually.
Just  call setRefreshComplete on the pullToRefreshLayout.

```
 mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
```

The bar is hidden and animations are fired.

Comment: I'm not asking how to show the animations, I'm asking how I can set the animations -- so to change the behaviour of the slide in/out.

Comment: Oh sorry, You can't change the animation by using a different HeaderTransfer. Default the DefaultHeaderTransformer is used. You can use ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity()).options(Options.create().headerTransformer(...) to set a custom one. And the custom HeaderTransformer overrides the function hideHeaderView.